# Need to get the response and to have change in ajax jquery GUI

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have the restful webservices call from the Jquery ajax and getting the response in json object.
Jquery HTML:

```
$.ajax({
                                        url: "mcrs/object/api/Lighting",
                                        type: "POST",
                                        traditional: true,
                                        dataType: "json",                                        
                                        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                                        async: "false",
                                        data:JSON.stringify(postdata),                                    
                                        success: function (ResData) {
                                        },
                                        error: function (error, data) {
                                            console.log(error);
                                        }
                                    });                                
                                }       
                            });
```

And writing the response object for the restful webservices in java

```
@POST
    @Path("api/{subsystem}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response changeStatus(@PathParam("subsystem") String subsystem,
            /*@FormParam("result")*/ String result) {
    }
```

I got the response below and which is correct

changeStatus:88 - Reponse OutboundJaxrsResponse{status=200, reason=OK, hasEntity=true, closed=false, buffered=false}

Depending upon the reponse need to update the status whether the value is on/off in the label tag.
            str = '

**Status :** ' + '' + **onoffStat** + '';

How can I achieve this in ajax and want to have the refreshing the div tag for every 2 seconds.

Please help me.

Comment: What is "the status" that you want to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use Javascript polling. Try out something like this:

```
function ajaxPoll(){
     $.ajax({
                                        url: "mcrs/object/api/Lighting",
                                        type: "POST",
                                        traditional: true,
                                        dataType: "json",                                        
                                        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                                        async: "false",
                                        data:JSON.stringify(postdata),                                    
                                        success: function (ResData) {
                                            tag.str = 'Status : ' + '' + ResData.status + '';
                                        },
                                        error: function (error, data) {
                                            console.log(error);
                                        }
                                    });                                
                                }       
                            });  
}

setInterval(ajaxPoll, 2000);
```

Hope you sort it out :)